# How to print multi line texts in run time using DOM elements using HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am stuck with how to print multi line texts and I don't know how to achieve it.
I also tried looking similar questions to print multi line but none of them were doing it in run time.... Its just they print or return multi line texts.

Thanks in advance.

```js
function typo() {
    var currentText = document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML;
    var x = '<br>' + '<div><p class=bubble>' + '<br>' + document.getElementById("myText").value + '</p></div>';
    document.getElementById("myText").value = "";
    var y = document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = currentText + x;

    var z = document.getElementById("wrapper");
    z.scrollTop = z.scrollHeight;

    document.getElementById("myText").focus();
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
    <textarea  type="text" id="myText" value=""></textarea>
    <button onclick="typo()" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btn-chat">Send</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the newline characters (`\n`) with HTML line breaks (`<br>`):

```js
function typo() {
   var currentText = document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML;
    var x = '<br>'+'<div><p class=bubble>'+'<br>' + document.getElementById("myText").value.split('\n').join('<br>') + '</p></div>';
    document.getElementById("myText").value = "";
    var y = document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = currentText + x ;

    var z = document.getElementById("wrapper");
    z.scrollTop = z.scrollHeight;
   
    document.getElementById("myText").focus();  
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<textarea  type="text" id="myText" value=""></textarea>
  <button onclick="typo()" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btn-chat">Send</button>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML doesn't recognize the standard newline character as a line break. To break the line, you need to replace all the occurrences of new line characters (`\n`) with `<br>` tags:

```js
function typo() {
  var currentText = document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML;
  var x = '<br>' + '<div><p class=bubble>' + '<br>' + document.getElementById("myText").value.replace(/\n/g, '<br>') + '</p></div>';
  document.getElementById("myText").value = "";
  var y = document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = currentText + x;

  var z = document.getElementById("wrapper");
  z.scrollTop = z.scrollHeight;

  document.getElementById("myText").focus();
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<textarea type="text" id="myText" value=""></textarea>
<button onclick="typo()" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btn-chat">Send</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add css snippet

```
#wrapper {white-space:pre-wrap;}
```